# Google Speech to Text (Speech Recognition) is Only Recognizing the First Few Seconds of Audio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm using Google's Speech-to-Text API in node js. It returns the recognition of the first few words, but then ignores the remainder of the audio file. The cut-off point is around 5-7 seconds into any uploaded file.

I've tried [synchronous speech recognition for shorter audio files](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize).
(Example using an MP3 file shown below)

```
    filename = './TEST/test.mp3';

    const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

    //configure the request:
    const config = {
        enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
        sampleRateHertz: 44100,
        encoding: 'MP3',
        languageCode: 'en-US',
    };
    const audio = {
        content: fs.readFileSync(filename).toString('base64'),
    };
    const request = {
        config: config,
        audio: audio,
    };
    
    // Detects speech in the audio file
    const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
```

And I've also tried [asynchronous recognition for longer audio files](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize)
(Example using a WAV file shown below)

```
filename = './TEST/test.wav';

const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

//configure the request:
const config = {
     enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
     languageCode: 'en-US',
};
const audio = {
     content: fs.readFileSync(filename).toString('base64'),
};
const request = {
     config: config,
     audio: audio,
};

//Do a longRunningRecognize request
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
const [response] = await operation.promise();
```

I've tried each of these implementations with both WAV files and MP3. The result is always exactly the same: good recognition for the first 5 seconds, then nothing at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you printing the results? Are you printing the results just like in the sample code you followed?

Answer (score 1):

@Ricco D was absolutely right, I was printing the results incorrectly...

When you try to transcribe longer files, Google Speech to Text will break up your transcription based on when it detects pauses in speech.

Your response.results[] array will have multiple entries that you need to loop through to print the full transcript.

See the docs for more detail:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#responses